# Freeze drying Yeast

Tags: yeast

I have made and nurtured natural yeast for baking in the past. Problem is if you don't bake on a regular basis, the cost and effort of maintaining your live yeast culture is crazy. I recently purchased a freeze dryer (love it!!) and was wondering if I could freeze dry my live yeast culture and use it like dry yeast.

Comment: Yeast as in sourdough culture?

Comment: yes. I think i've read that if you let your yeast dry and become flaky then you save it can reconstitute it later. I wanted to take it a step further and have a long lasting storage. The only other reference i've seen referred to is a bio control yeast candida Sake, whereby you add 10% skim milk to the yeast which changes its viability from .2% to 30-30% after freeze-drying.

Comment: I've never done it, but years ago I read that you could spread sourdough starter out thinly, then let it dry.  You can then break it into flakes and store it as a precaution against losing the rest of your starter.  So it might not require freeze drying.

Comment: you can put your culture in the fridge and then you only need to feed it weekly, or if you bake very infrequently you can create a new culture each time (it takes 1-2 weeks until it's ready for baking)

Answer (score 1):

I successfully freeze dried my kefir grains and sourdough starter by first adding in 20-25% (weight/weight) sugar and freezing it into small disks.  The sugar stabilizes it against the freeze drying process and I observed no significant drop in activity following reconstitution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).